# Android studio ADB not responding. manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am running my Android studio on Ubuntu 14.04,its was working fine but suddenly its shows the following error while do build my project.

Error message:

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'
```

I have tried the following in terminal but it also not worked

```
node@node-Lenovo-G550:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb kill-server
The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

but I have adb under platform-tools folder, I do not know why its says "not installed", How I can resolve this?. Please help me.

[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLzP2.png)

Updated question:
I have added path as following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/node/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

then executed this: `./adb kill-server`

it gives me the following error

```
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

if I run as `adb kill-server` it gives `bash: /home/node/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Answer (score 0):

The directory where add is located, is not in your `PATH` variable. You could add it to your `PATH` variable (`export PATH=$PATH:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` I believe). You can also use `./adb kill-server`. Note the ./ in front of adb. Because you are executing an executable in your current directory, you need ./

Comment: I have added the path as following `export PATH=$PATH:/home/node/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`, and run the `./adb` command it gives the following error:
`bash: ./adb: No such file or directory` please help me to find out the probelm

Comment: If you have added the directory where adb is located to your path, then you can you don't need ./ in front of adb. Your initial command (`adb kill-server`) will suffice

Comment: Tried, it gives `bash: /home/node/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: That doesn't sound familiar to me and it is not an error of adb. A quick google gave me this http://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file, but I'm not sure if that's the same cause

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following steps and its works.

first run following comments to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Second step is move the ADB and Fast boot to our SDK location.

```
cp /usr/bin/adb <path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platform-tools/adb
cp /usr/bin/fastboot <path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platformtools/fastboot
```

Last run the command:
SDK location/platform-tools/ adb kill-server.